# SonarLint for IntelliJ not showing critical and blocker vulnerabilities

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have enabled sonar lint plugin to my IntelliJ IDE for capturing code violations during my development. i have connected to my remote SonarQube server for rules binding.

Plugin capture rules for major, minor issues and not capturing critical rule violations on my local IDE.

my binding updated to latest rules , but critical issues are not getting picked up by the intellji plugin.

[image]

dont know how to fix this on my machine, or should i need to raise a bug?

EDIT

All critical issues are not getting reported.

sonarqube reporting below critical issue

> An 'int' is expected rather than a String

[image]

but in intellji sonarlint plugin, the above issue is not getting reported.

[image]

Comment: please add information which rules found critical issues

Comment: i have added more information which you have requested.

Comment: I guess you use [squid:S2275](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2275) rule so SonarLint should support it. Please add a screen from your project `Administration → Quality Profiles` and SonarLint `Logs` tab.